# Why do Dummit & Foote require an ideal also be a subring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

On page 242 of Abstract Algebra, 3rd Ed., by Dummit & Foote, they write:

[image: Abstract Algebra, 3rd Ed., Dummit & Foote]

However, in my lecture notes, there is a line that says

> **Definition.** (Ideal.) Let $R$ be a ring. A subgroup $I$ of the underlying abelian group $R$ is called an *ideal* if $rx \in I$ for all $r \in R, x \in I$.
> Note that $I$ may not contain [the multiplicative identity], so it may not be a subring. In fact, if $1 \in I$, then $I$ must be the whole ring!

Surely this is a typo in Dummit and Foote, right? Like my lecture notes suggest, if $1 \in I$ then $I = R$ since $r \in I$ for all $r \in R$.

Wikipedia seems to agree that an ideal need not be a subring.

**EDIT**: I realised Dummit & Foote doesn't require a subring to include the multiplicative identity. This answers my original question, but begs a new one: why would D&F define a subring to not necessarily be itself a ring?

Comment: I don't know the details of these two books - but is it possible one of them considers rings to be unital and one doesn't?

Comment: You should check if the the book defines "ring" as "ring with $1$" or not. If the former, then subrings should also contain $1$ (you might want to check this definition as well) and it should be a typo. If the latter, then the current version is the intended statement by the authors: you'll just have to accept that the textbook and your lecturer are using different notations and that this might come up upon further reading.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! It turns out D&F doesn't require rings to be unital.

Comment: See also [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#History) for a short summary of the debate ring-with-1 versus rng.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comments on the original post suggested, the book by Dummit & Foote does *not* require rings to be unital (contain a multiplicative identity). Naturally — and to answer the question in the edit — subrings need not be unital rings either, according to Dummit and Foote.

Comment: What you've written is perfectly correct, but just another note: that's not to say that the ideal *doesn't* have an identity. It's just that proper ideals will certainly not *share* the same identity as the containing ring.